# How should I get the coefficient?

Tags: r, error-handling

gus

I have two columns about returns (x1 and x2) and want to use loop to get the coefficient of them.

The number of observations are 120

This is my code, but it doesn't work.

`j <- 20
for(i in 1:100){
a <- lm(x1[i:i+j-1] ~ x2[i:i+j-1])
}`

How should I change it.

Comment: can you write the algorithm ? pseudocode or something. This piece of code can be misleading

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that i:i+j-1 produces a single number. Use:

```
i:(i+j-1)
```

This should work

Comment: As @timfaber says, it is necessary to write the number between parenthesis, because if not it is only going to select the first value after the `:`

Comment: Thanks guys, correct the wrong place.
I know what to do.